# Disabling all parent node in JavaFX while keeping all its children clickable

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I am trying to create a JavaFX tree view which has checkbox tree items. I require all the nodes which have children should be disabled. But all the children of these nodes should be clickable.

Basically, if the tree item is a leaf it should be enabled and clickable.

This is the current code I have used. Which disables nodes with children but the problem is, since it is disabled I cannot access the code inside a parent.

```
public class App extends Application
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    launch(args);
}

private List<Dependant> myList = new ArrayList();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem("Root");
    final List<CheckBoxTreeItem<String>> treeItems = new ArrayList(6);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> item = new CheckBoxTreeItem("L0"+i+"");
        item.setIndependent(true);
        treeItems.add(item);  
        myList.add(new Dependant("0"+i+"", "type1"));
    }
    rootItem.getChildren().addAll(treeItems);

    rootItem.setExpanded(true);
    rootItem.setIndependent(true);
    CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootItem2 = new CheckBoxTreeItem("folder");
    final List<CheckBoxTreeItem<String>> treeItems2 = new ArrayList(6);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> item = new CheckBoxTreeItem("L1"+i+"");
        item.setIndependent(true);
        treeItems2.add(item); 
        myList.add(new Dependant("0"+i+"", "type2"));
    }
    rootItem2.getChildren().addAll(treeItems2);
    rootItem2.setIndependent(true);
    rootItem.getChildren().set(2,rootItem2);

    TreeView tree = new TreeView(rootItem);

    tree.setCellFactory((Object item) -> {

        final CheckBoxTreeCell<String> cell = new CheckBoxTreeCell();

        cell.itemProperty().addListener((obs,s,s1)->{

            cell.disableProperty().unbind();
            if(s1!=null && !s1.isEmpty()){
                BooleanProperty prop = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
                prop.set((s1.equals("folder")));
                cell.disableProperty().bind(prop);
            }
        });
        return cell;
    });

    tree.setRoot(rootItem);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(tree);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

}
```

This is not the final code of my application, it is just a sample code which I tried out before doing the final implementation.

As you can see from the code, the disabled property of the cell is binded to whether or not the name is equal to "folder" as the method `isLeaf()` is not available.

If anyone is wondering why I need to disable all parent nodes it is because in the final implementation, I require only one item be selected in the entire treeview (as clicking a parent node will select all its children as well!).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you iterate all the children and enable them after disabling the parent?

Comment: please make your example standalone (f.i. by adding the Dependant class)

Comment: it's always wrong to burden the view (== cell) with data logic: if you need single selection you need to implement the logic in your data (== treeItem) and then let the cell simply listen

Comment: ... and why do you think that treeItem.isLeaf is not available?

Comment: "*clicking a parent node will select all its children as well!*" This is not the default behavior. We want to be able to copy-paste your example and run it to see this ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the question is a typical [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) (asking for solving a problem that was introduced by trying to solve the real requirement in the wrong way), that real problem is interesting enough to give it a quick try :)

The real requirement as I understand it:

- have a tree with items that allow selection (via checkBox)
- allow only a single item to be selected at any time

As always, the basic approach is add such logic into a general model (vs. the view = cell). For a Treeview, the model is the treeItem - which by itself cannot handle inter-item logic, so it needs a controller with a broader knowledge.

Fortunately, fx provides support for select-one-in-many: the role of *one* is played by a Toggle, the role of *many* is played by a ToggleGroup. Now all we have to do is to apply that support to our context:

- implement a custom TreeItem that is a Toggle (the example below extends CheckBoxTreeItem)
- in application code use that item and add it to ToggleGroups as needed

Some code example (beware: incomplete implementation and not formally tested - just to point the direction!)

```
public class TreeSingleSelectedCheckboxWithToggle extends Application {

    /**
     * A custom CheckBoxTreeItem that implements Toggle.
     * 
     * To control which/how many items can be selected at any
     * time, add them to one or several ToggleGroups.
     * 
     * @author Jeanette Winzenburg, Berlin
     */
    public static class ToggleTreeItem<T> extends CheckBoxTreeItem<T>
        implements Toggle {


        public ToggleTreeItem() {
            super();
            init();
        }

        public ToggleTreeItem(T value) {
            super(value);
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            // basically c&p from ToggleButton 
            selectedProperty().addListener(ov -> {
                final boolean selected = isSelected();
                final ToggleGroup tg = getToggleGroup();
                // Note: these changes need to be done before selectToggle/clearSelectedToggle since
                // those operations change properties and can execute user code, possibly modifying selected property again
                if (tg != null) {
                    if (selected) {
                        tg.selectToggle(ToggleTreeItem.this);
                    } else if (tg.getSelectedToggle() == ToggleTreeItem.this) {
                        // reflective access to package-private api  - use your own utility method
                        FXUtils.invokeMethod(ToggleGroup.class, tg, "clearSelectedToggle");
                       // tg.clearSelectedToggle();
                    }
                }

            });
        }
        /**
         * The {@link ToggleGroup} to which this {@code ToggleButton} belongs. A
         * {@code ToggleButton} can only be in one group at any one time. If the
         * group is changed, then the button is removed from the old group prior to
         * being added to the new group.
         */
        private ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup> toggleGroup;
        @Override
        public final void setToggleGroup(ToggleGroup value) {
            toggleGroupProperty().set(value);
        }

        @Override
        public final ToggleGroup getToggleGroup() {
            return toggleGroup == null ? null : toggleGroup.get();
        }

        @Override
        public final ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup> toggleGroupProperty() {
            if (toggleGroup == null) {
                toggleGroup = new ObjectPropertyBase<ToggleGroup>() {
                    private ToggleGroup old;
                    @Override protected void invalidated() {
                        final ToggleGroup tg = get();
                        if (tg != null && !tg.getToggles().contains(ToggleTreeItem.this)) {
                            if (old != null) {
                                old.getToggles().remove(ToggleTreeItem.this);
                            }
                            tg.getToggles().add(ToggleTreeItem.this);
                        } else if (tg == null) {
                            old.getToggles().remove(ToggleTreeItem.this);
                        }

                        old = tg;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object getBean() {
                        return ToggleTreeItem.this;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getName() {
                        return "toggleGroup";
                    }
                };
            }
            return toggleGroup;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getUserData() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void setUserData(Object value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public ObservableMap<Object, Object> getProperties() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        ToggleTreeItem<String> rootItem = new ToggleTreeItem<>("Root");
        toggleGroup.getToggles().add(rootItem);
        final List<ToggleTreeItem<String>> treeItems = new ArrayList<>(6);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            ToggleTreeItem<String> item = new ToggleTreeItem<>("L0" + i + "");
            item.setIndependent(true);
            treeItems.add(item);
            toggleGroup.getToggles().add(item);
            myList.add(new Dependant("0" + i + "", "type1"));
        }
        rootItem.getChildren().addAll(treeItems);

        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        rootItem.setIndependent(true);
        ToggleTreeItem<String> rootItem2 = new ToggleTreeItem<>("folder");
        toggleGroup.getToggles().add(rootItem2);
        final List<ToggleTreeItem<String>> treeItems2 = new ArrayList<>(6);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            ToggleTreeItem<String> item = new ToggleTreeItem<>("L1" + i + "");
            item.setIndependent(true);
            treeItems2.add(item);
            toggleGroup.getToggles().add(item);
            myList.add(new Dependant("0" + i + "", "type2"));
        }
        rootItem2.getChildren().addAll(treeItems2);
        rootItem2.setIndependent(true);
        rootItem.getChildren().set(2, rootItem2);

        TreeView tree = new TreeView<>(rootItem);

        tree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.forTreeView());

        tree.setRoot(rootItem);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tree);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Dependant {

        String one;
        String two;
        public Dependant(String one, String two) {
            this.one = one;
            this.two = two;
        }

    }

    private List<Dependant> myList = new ArrayList();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @kleopatra. Your code did solve the immediate problem but it did not work during the final implementation. But I should be able to fix it looking at your code. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, apologize for the late reply as I was a bit sick the past couple of days.